# The word "darg "

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What would the word darg mean in the novel 'the invisible man' where a person has been bit by a dog of a carrier  person.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Darg* is an approximation of the way Hall and Fearenside (and evidently everyone in Iping village) pronounced "dog" in their dialect:

> "He wuz bit," said Hall. "I'd better go and see to en," and he trotted after the stranger. He met Mrs. Hall in the passage. "Carrier's darg," he said "bit en."

*The Invisible Man, by H G Wells - Chapter III*

Peter below mentions that in England, where this story is set, the *R* would not be pronounced as *R*, so a closer but uglier phonetic approximation would be "dahg" (IPA /dɑːg/), as opposed to the American *dawg* (/dɔg/), or the clipped British *dug* (I'm not familiar enough with IPA to represent this - halfway between *aw* and *uh* - but listen to the [UK pronunciation in Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog) to hear what I mean).

Comment: Thankew...u answered quick as if u were like stanger eager for his luggage

Comment: Ha, you don't even know, I might be invisible. You can mark my answer as accepted if it answered you to your satisfaction!

Comment: I dont have enough reputation, hey what can u say about mr.hall glimpse of strange sight

Comment: Americans should realize that H.G. Wells is non-rhotic, so this is pronounced roughly *dahg*. There's not actually an 'r' in it.

Comment: @PeterShor Maybe I should attempt to isolate the difference between dog and dahg...

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think it's /dɒg/ but /dɑːg/. /The word *darg* rhymes with the first syllable of *lager* and not *logger*. (Although this explanation isn't going to make sense to those people who pronounce *lager* and *logger* the same.)

Comment: @PeterShor Fixed. IPA isn't my strong point yet - I'd like to learn it. Why is the /ɑ/ made long? What would /dɑg/ sound like?

Comment: The /ɑ/ is long because British English (unlike American English) has a semi-phonemic distinction between short and long vowels, and IPA for British English indicates them. The short vowel /ɑ/ doesn't occur in standard British English, but some dialects in England pronounce *dug* with a short vowel that is very close to /dɑg/. So /ɑ/ is always long when you use length markings for IPA in British English.

Comment: Please don't assume this is "the British pronunciation". Iping is in West Sussex, so would use approximately the Kentish drawl, as opposed to the West Country burr, the Midlands whine or the Welsh lilt. I understand there are also English speakers north of Derby, but Heaven knows how they speak.

Comment: I am natively American, and know little further than the absolute answer to the question. I wouldn't mind if someone edited my answer to make the pronunciation analysis more complete or correct. Or you could add your own answer!